# Pandas resample by day without filling missing dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with several date fields including hours. I want to use one of them as my df index, and count the number of entries which where created each day. In other words, if I have:

```
Date | Several features
2020-02-08 10h00 | ...
2020-02-08 11h00 | ...
2020-02-10 10h00 | ...
2020-02-10 11h00 | ...
2020-02-10 13h00 | ...
```

I want to get:

```
2020-02-08 | 2
2020-02-10 | 3
```

For this, I am doing:

```
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])
df = df.set_index('datetime')
df.resample('D')["id"].count()
```

where `id` is an unique identifier each entry has.

However, I am getting the following output:

```
2020-02-08 | 2
2020-02-09 | 0
2020-02-10 | 3
```

How can I get rid of the "2020-02-09" row? I only want to count the occurences of the days I have on my dataset, not the ones I do not have.

Comment: IMO, `resample` is not required. Just a `groupby` with `count()` or `size()` should get you the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) with [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])
df = df.groupby(df["datetime"].dt.date)["id"].count()
```

If need `DatetimeIndex` working also well in oldier pandas versions use [`Series.dt.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html):

```
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])
df = df.groupby(df["datetime"].dt.normalize())["id"].count()
```

In your solution if are generated missing values remove them:

```
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])
df = df.set_index('datetime').resample('D')["id"].count().dropna()
```

Or remove `0` rows:

```
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])
df = df.set_index('datetime').resample('D')["id"].count().loc[lambda x: x!= 0]
```

Comment: I'd stay away from `dt.date` as Pandas doesn't play very well with `datetime.date`.

Comment: @QuangHoang - Ya, in some oldier versions, in new one should working better, but agree, I can add normalize alternative. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I use your solution and then I want to group by month, is it possible or in that case I should use my approach and go for a `.resample('M')` ? @jezrael

Comment: @Luiscri Tnes is possible use resample solutions from my answers or `df = df.groupby(df["datetime"].dt.to_period('m')) ["id"].count()`